# Merge cells with same content HTML

Tags: html, merge, cell

I'm trying to merge cells of a table, I'd like it to look like "break on column" SQLPlus feature but I have no idea how to do this.

Example:

```
|monday | refrref |
|monday | referfr |
```

would be

```
|monday | refrref |
|       | referfr |
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share what you have done so far.

Comment: Nothing, I only put my MySQL queries in table like <tr><td> DAY </td><td> TEXT </td></tr>

Answer (score 0):

Nailed it

Used a PHP Class to do it. Sorry for french variables names

```
class jours {
    var $jour;
    var $horaire;
    var $nbr=0;
}

$lundi = new jours();
$mardi = new jours();
$mercredi = new jours();
$jeudi = new jours();
$vendredi = new jours();

$lundi->jour = "Lundi";
$mardi->jour = "Mardi";
$mercredi->jour = "Mercredi";
$jeudi->jour = "Jeudi";
$vendredi->jour = "Vendredi";

// rest of the code, queries

switch ($infos['jour']){
    case 'Lundi':
        $lundi->horaire[$lundi->nbr] = $infos['horaire'];
        $lundi->nbr++;
        break;
    case 'Mardi':
        $mardi->horaire[$mardi->nbr] = $infos['horaire'];
        $mardi->nbr++;
        break;
    case 'Mercredi':
        $mercredi->horaire[$mercredi->nbr] = $infos['horaire'];
        $mercredi->nbr++;
        break;
    case 'Jeudi':
        $jeudi->horaire[$jeudi->nbr] = $infos['horaire'];
        $jeudi->nbr++;
        break;
    case 'Vendredi':
        $vendredi->horaire[$vendredi->nbr] = $infos['horaire'];
        $vendredi->nbr++;
        break;
}



// display the table

$affichage = array($lundi,$mardi,$mercredi,$jeudi,$vendredi); //used this array to be able to make the for loop later
echo '<table>';
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    if($affichage[$i]->nbr != 0){
        echo '<tr><td>'; //1st line 1st column
        echo $affichage[$i]->jour;
        echo '</td><td>'; //1st line 2nd column
        echo $affichage[$i]->horaire['0'];
        echo '</td></tr>';
        for($j=1; $j < $affichage[$i]->nbr; $j++){ //other lines and columns
            echo '<tr><td></td><td>';
            echo $affichage[$i]->horaire[$j];
            echo '</td></tr>';
        }
    }
}
echo '</table>';
```